# Does wet impurity which dried before make me impure if I touch it with wet hands?

Tags: taharah

Does touching dry impurity with wet hands make me impure?

If I touch something that has a wet impurity (ex. unrine) on it but it dries, then it becomes wet again during the time of touching with my hand. Do I need to clean my hands?

Or suppose someone pee'd on my bag but it dried later, then the impure part became again and I touched the wet bag with my hand, so do I need to clean my hand before praying?

*Note: Dry impurity can't make someone impure.*

Answer (score 0):

If the impure dry hand comes into contact with something wet, that thing will only be considered impure if traces of the original urine can be detected on it. Traces of impurity can be detected by its color, smell, or taste. If no trace of the impurity is found on the object it is pure. [Shurunbulali, Maraqi al-Falah]

-Seekers guidance